# Using Ember and Handlebars, how do you dynamically declare parameter within template block?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

For example, I have a script like this, which defines a new div, annotated with a page number

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="page-template">
    <div class = 'page'>
       The page is  <b>{{ App.pageView_1.pageNumber }}</b>
    <div>
</script>
```

The corresponding view:

```
App.pageView_1 = App.PageView.create({
    templateName: 'page-template',
    pageNumber: 1,
})
```

And I want to dynamically declare new views, each one with a different pageNumber field and view name, so:

```
  App.pageView_2 = App.PageView.create({
      pageNumber: 2,
  });

  App.pageView_3 = App.PageView.create({
      pageNumber: 3,
  });
```

note the templateName field has been omitted for clarity.

The problem is the param within the template block has to change to {{ App.pageView_2.pageNumber }} and so on.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit closer to the ember way:

```
{{#each App.pagesController}}
    {{#view App.PageView contextBinding="this"}}
        {{pageNumber}}
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

And for the controller:

```
App.pagesController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [{ pageNumber: 1 }, { pageNumber: 2 }, { pageNumber: 3 }]
});
```

By the way, you probably want the `templateName` to be set when the view is originally defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{view App.pageView pageNumber="2"}}
  {{pageNumber}}
{{/view}}
```

should work but seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly declare a generic view

```
App.pageView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "page_template"
  classNames: ['page']
})
```

**page_template.handlebars**

```
The page is {{view.pageNumber}}
```

Now, that you have declared this, use it wherever you want doing the following:

```
{{view App.pageView pageNumber="1"}}
```

This should work I guess...